# Can't create JVM Unrecognized option: --module-path

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm working to get a maven project with scenebuilder fxml on intellij.
I followed this tutoriel : https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx
But at the end, when I try to javafx:run I got this error

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< svkiyo:diamond.server >------------------------
[INFO] Building diamond.server 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.1:run (default-cli) @ diamond.server ---
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: --module-path
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXRunMojo.java:525)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXRunMojo.java:487)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute (JavaFXRunMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
```

I already tryied to "compile", "package" etc...

Comment: which version of `javac` are you using? `--module-path` was introduced with Java 9, alongside with project jigsaw.

Comment: `javac 1.8.0_111` So I got the wrong version of Java ? To solve the problem, Have I to upgrade Java to 9 ?

Comment: Java 9+, yes. I would recommend Java 11, since it is a LTS. Keep in mind that this version of Java will no longer include JavaFx, so you would need to add it to your dependencies.

Comment: for adding JavaFx dependencies re Java9+, javafx plugin is good https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin